# Handling Null value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to generate data per sales people per week while comparing my results with last week and subtracting last week from current week. Sometimes current week doesn't have any value. I would like to handle that situation by replacing it by '0'. I am not really good at this so I am seeking help.

```
SELECT t2.emp_name, 
       t2.pipelinetarget, 
       Sum(t0.maxsumloc)               AS SaleOpp, 
       Datepart(ww, t0.opendate)       AS [Week #], 
       Isnull ((SELECT Sum(maxsumloc) AS Expr1 
                FROM   dbo.oopr AS A 
                WHERE  ( slpcode = t1.slpcode ) 
                       AND ( Datepart(ww, opendate) = 
                             Datepart(ww, Getdate()) - 1 ) 
                       AND ( Datepart(yy, opendate) = Datepart(yy, Getdate()) ) 
                GROUP  BY slpcode), 0) AS LastWeek, 
       Isnull ((SELECT Sum(maxsumloc) AS Expr1 
                FROM   dbo.oopr AS A 
                WHERE  ( Datepart(ww, opendate) = Datepart(ww, Getdate()) ) 
                       AND ( Datepart(yy, opendate) = Datepart(yy, Getdate()) ) 
                       AND ( maxsumloc >= 10000.00 ) 
                       AND ( slpcode = t1.slpcode ) 
                GROUP  BY slpcode), 0) AS [SumOf-Opp-obove-10k], 
       Isnull ((SELECT Count(opprid) AS Expr1 
                FROM   dbo.oopr AS A 
                WHERE  ( Datepart(ww, opendate) = Datepart(ww, Getdate()) ) 
                       AND ( Datepart(yy, opendate) = Datepart(yy, Getdate()) ) 
                       AND ( maxsumloc >= 10000.00 ) 
                       AND ( slpcode = t1.slpcode ) 
                GROUP  BY slpcode), 0) AS [#-Opp-obove-10k], 
       Isnull ((SELECT Sum(maxsumloc) AS Expr1 
                FROM   dbo.oopr AS A 
                WHERE  ( Datepart(ww, opendate) = Datepart(ww, Getdate()) ) 
                       AND ( Datepart(yy, opendate) = Datepart(yy, Getdate()) ) 
                       AND ( maxsumloc < 10000.00 ) 
                       AND ( slpcode = t1.slpcode ) 
                GROUP  BY slpcode), 0) AS [SumOf-Opp-below-10k], 
       Isnull ((SELECT Count(opprid) AS Expr1 
                FROM   dbo.oopr AS A 
                WHERE  ( Datepart(ww, opendate) = Datepart(ww, Getdate()) ) 
                       AND ( Datepart(yy, opendate) = Datepart(yy, Getdate()) ) 
                       AND ( maxsumloc < 10000.00 ) 
                       AND ( slpcode = t1.slpcode ) 
                GROUP  BY slpcode), 0) AS [#-Opp-below-10k] 
FROM   dbo.oslp AS t1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.oopr AS t0 
                    ON t1.slpcode = t0.slpcode 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[user_qsalestarget(salesrep)] AS t2 
                    ON t2.emp_name = t1.slpname 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ocrd AS t4 
                    ON t4.cardcode = t0.cardcode 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[user_clusters(sp)] AS t5 
                    ON t5.emp_name = t1.slpname 
WHERE  ( Datepart(ww, t0.opendate) = Datepart(ww, Getdate()) ) 
       AND ( Datepart(yy, t0.opendate) = Datepart(yy, Getdate()) ) 
       AND ( t5.title = 'Outside Sales Rep' ) 
GROUP  BY t2.emp_name, 
          t1.slpcode, 
          Datepart(ww, t0.opendate), 
          t2.pipelinetarget
```

Comment: Any chance we could get some create table statements to better be able to help you?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the coalesce function eg "SELECT COALESCE(thePossibleNullValue, 0) FROM mytable" which returns the first non-null value ie either your value or zero if it's null in this example